# C# unit test: UnauthorizedAccessException when using API that uses network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, windows-phone-8.1, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to create Coded UI Tests for my Windows Phone 8.1 app, but are having some difficulties with my test methods.

In my test methods, I first invoke a method that connects with the API of my backend. The API call makes my backend send a notification to my app. What I want my UI test to do now, is test and verify that the UI is properly displaying the notification and data it received.

**In short:** I want to make a test which triggers a notification from my backend, and then verifies that the UI behaves as expected after receiving it.

The problem with this is that, whenever I call the method, which calls the backend API, I get an:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Use of networking APIs requires
>   the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability to be defined in the application
>   manifest

This flag is properly set in the application manifest itself and for good reasons, I cannot set it in my Coded UI Test project, since it has no application manifest.

I tried working around this by making a third project with only the API (so that I have a phone, test and API project). The test-project would now invoke the API calling method in another project, but that did not help.

Are there any workarounds to this and if so, what would they be?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211128/how-to-add-capabilities-to-coded-ui-test-windows-phone-8-1-project-in-c

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I already had a look at that link, and I understand their point (it's a good one - I want to test the UI of the project, not the individual network elements). Anyway my niché problem in this case is that I have two apps: One for the consumers and one for retail. The consumer-app needs to approve requests from the retail-app, so I have little to nothing to test UI-wise, unless a request is done from the merchant-app. That's why I try code-behind in my consumer-test to send a request, so there's a request to act on, whenever I start my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way around it in Coded UI Test, which seems like a huge drawback, as our app works against an API!

We dropped Coded UI Test and instead went with Winium-StoreApps (can be found on Github). It does the UI testing nicely, is way faster than Coded UI Tests, and allows for API access, file system access, etc. meanwhile.